# Convert arrays in a python list to pandas, to eventually df.sum()

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have data that looks like this below. Its all in a list in an array format. Ultimately I am trying to sum all these values in the Python list. Is pandas the best option for this? I am attempting to create a dataframe named `test.`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


test = [array([[1083.8748]], dtype=float32), array([[998.98773]], dtype=float32), array([[1137.0487]], dtype=float32), array([[1077.2798]], dtype=float32), array([[926.41284]], dtype=float32),
array([[1030.7125]], dtype=float32), array([[1028.0048]], dtype=float32), array([[523.9799]], dtype=float32), array([[1125.092]], dtype=float32), array([[1119.7738]], dtype=float32),
array([[918.6966]], dtype=float32), array([[1112.5186]], dtype=float32), array([[555.6942]], dtype=float32), array([[1096.5643]], dtype=float32), array([[826.35657]], dtype=float32),
array([[1014.35406]], dtype=float32), array([[1027.6962]], dtype=float32), array([[924.20087]], dtype=float32), array([[1035.217]], dtype=float32), array([[1008.9658]], dtype=float32),
array([[970.54047]], dtype=float32), array([[847.0671]], dtype=float32), array([[913.5519]], dtype=float32), array([[1047.0747]], dtype=float32), array([[920.0606]], dtype=float32),
array([[994.2266]], dtype=float32), array([[991.4501]], dtype=float32), array([[972.43256]], dtype=float32), array([[934.8802]], dtype=float32), array([[912.04004]], dtype=float32), array([[1131.297]], dtype=float32)]


df = pd.DataFrame(test)

print(test.sum())
```

This fails with the error: `NameError: name 'array' is not defined`

Can anyone give me a tip? Thanks

Comment: replace the `array` like`np.array([[1083.8748]], dtype='float32')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is already pointing you to the right direction.

```
# Your case
array([1,2], dtype=float32)

# Output
NameError: name 'array' is not defined


#Correct case
np.array([1,2], dtype='float32')

# Output
array([1., 2.], dtype=float32)
```

So two things are wrong in your case `array` should be `np.array` and `float32` should be `'float32'`

**Plus**
You cannot pass `pd.DataFrame` a 1d array. So in this case you can use `pd.Series`. Heres your code fixed:

```
test = [np.array([[1083.8748]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[998.98773]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1137.0487]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1077.2798]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[926.41284]], dtype='float32'),
np.array([[1030.7125]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1028.0048]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[523.9799]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1125.092]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1119.7738]], dtype='float32'),
np.array([[918.6966]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1112.5186]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[555.6942]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1096.5643]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[826.35657]], dtype='float32'),
np.array([[1014.35406]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1027.6962]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[924.20087]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1035.217]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1008.9658]], dtype='float32'),
np.array([[970.54047]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[847.0671]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[913.5519]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1047.0747]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[920.0606]], dtype='float32'),
np.array([[994.2266]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[991.4501]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[972.43256]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[934.8802]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[912.04004]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[1131.297]], dtype='float32')]

df = pd.Series(test)
print(df.head())

0    [[1083.8748]]
1    [[998.98773]]
2    [[1137.0487]]
3    [[1077.2798]]
4    [[926.41284]]
```